# Can I shorten this speech?

Tags: grammar, sentence, speech

> None of these are taken.

Can I shorten this above speech like below:

> None taken.

Is this process grammatically right? If it is right then what are the rules behind it?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What has not been "taken"? Are they seats, photographs, baths, etc.

Comment: What can be shortened and in which ways depends on the context. Given one context, the phrase could be shortened to just "none". Given a different context, the whole phrase can be incomprehensible or unidiomatic to begin with, and shortening it will turn it into gibberish. Given a third context, the whole phrase can be gibberish to begin with, but leaving some of the words out might actually fix that. You see where this is going. What is the context? Give us all the information that you have. If you can't work it out knowing all that you know, we can't work it out not knowing any of it.

Comment: "None of the bags are taken" is the real sentence

Answer (score 1):

"None taken" is actually used to reassure someone that they took no offense to something that was said in their previous statement. For example:

> Person A: "That sweater is ugly. No offense, though."
>
> Person B: "None taken."

So, the former will be the best option. However, you may want to specify what is being referred to by the pronoun *these*.